# "still be" vs "be still" order

Tags: word-order

I've faced two different orders in the same guide:

1. "Can he **be still** working?"
2. "Can they **still be** sleeping?"

Could you tell me why there is a difference? Maybe one of the sentences is composed incorrectly?

Comment: It's better to use adverbs like *still* before the copula.

Comment: In #1, the grouping is (*still working*), not (*be still*). Likewise, #2's grouping is (*be sleeping*), not (*still be*). So if you're focusing on "be", your question is really about whether someone can "be" (still working) and whether they can still "be" (sleeping).